# Subtracting and aggregating dates with millisecond precision

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with two columns that contain date-times, in particular, a `time_started` and a `time_ended`. I want to determine the duration defined by these two times and sum all the durations.

This is my attempt:

```
select strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f', sum(duration), 'unixepoch') 
from (
    select strftime('%s', time_ended) - strftime('%s', time_started) as duration
    from mytable
)
```

The reason why this doesn't work is that `strftime('%s', time_started)` returns the *integer* number of [seconds since 1970-01-01](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Which means I'm losing the milliseconds.

Is there any way to get the ***fractional*** number of seconds since 1970-01-01 instead?

Note that the date-time values have the same format of this example: "2013-04-24 14:57:30.661259".

---

**Update**, now using `julianday()`, by @LS_dev's suggestion in the answers:

```
select strftime('%H:%M:%f', sum(duration)) 
from (
    select julianday(time_ended) - julianday(time_started) as duration
    from mytable
)
```

Two issues remain though:

- The results of the sum have more 12 hours than they should (!)
- The milliseconds are being truncated to three digits, which looks like a limitation of `strftime()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JULIANDAY`:

```
select duration*24*60*60
from (
    select JULIANDAY(time_ended) - JULIANDAY('%s', time_started) as duration
    from mytable
)
```

EDIT: an "all-work-done-for-you" solution:

```
SELECT *, TIME("00:00", CAST(Duration AS INT)||' seconds')||SUBSTR(Duration-CAST(Duration AS INT), 2)
FROM (
    SELECT *, (JULIANDAY(time_ended) - JULIANDAY(time_started))*60*60*24 as Duration
    FROM mytable
)
```

Check in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6f3be/1)

Comment: That, I must say, is a bit of a sloppy answer :P But a useful one, as I think it points me in the right direction. Please check my updated question above. I'm still strugling with a part of it.